# USB ports suddenly stopped working Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: usb, 18.10

USB ports suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 18.10 after long time of normal usage.
`lsusb` command show nothing. When I boot system in recovery mode usb ports works normal. Can anyone help me ?

**Update**
I found some errors in dmesg

> [    1.040065] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
>   [    1.040071] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
>   [    1.041254] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x20007fc1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
>   [    1.041262] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
>   [    1.041264] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: No msi-x/msi found and no IRQ in BIOS
>   [    1.041268] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: startup error -22
>   [    1.041271] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
>   [    1.041286] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: init 0000:00:14.0 fail, -22

Comment: Do you have the same situation even after using it with live usb?

Comment: I don't have access to live usb right now. 
I forgot to say that on my laptop I have dual boot with Windows 10 and on Windows USB works fine.

Comment: Then download Ubuntu ISO, use unetbootin under windows to make one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in `syslog`, it's possible we got the same problem.

## my problem

I was trying to block some annoying messages in syslog, and I add in grub.cfg:

```
pci=nomsi
```

Unfortunately the device generating the annoying messages was the USB HUB,  since that gives the 'error -22` :

```
    [ 1.041264] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: No msi-x/msi found and no IRQ in BIOS
    [ 1.041268] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: startup error -22
```

## my solution

I've removed `pci=nomsi`  from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: What's the relation with the question? I can't seem to make a match.

Comment: @ThunderBird I was too much "ermetic", now I've edited the answer and I give a bit more context