# pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0

Tags: pcie

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. I recently cloned my system from a 2.5" SSD over to a new 2280 (via dd - aka it's an exact replica of the previous install). Everything runs smoothly, however I've noticed that sometimes I see the following during bootup or shutdown:

```
[  125.110891] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
[  125.110895] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  125.110898] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER:   device [10ec:5762] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
[  125.110899] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  125.118946] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
[  125.118950] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  125.118952] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER:   device [10ec:5762] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
[  125.118954] nvme 0000:04:00.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
...repeating
```

It only happens maybe 1 out of 10 reboots, and I've never seen any actual behavioral issues (i.e. crashes, etc). As a small side note, the only other difference I've noticed since moving over to the new SSD is that system audio is very subtly choppy ([as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698009/choppy-audio-after-cloning-kubuntu-to-new-ssd)).

I've found [some other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104219/what-does-pci-noaer-or-pci-nomsi-mean) that suggest getting rid of the "PCIe Bus Error" by adding `pci=nomsi` and `pci=noaer` to `/etc/default/grub`, but those all seem to be addressing other issues (i.e. Ubuntu can't install, or other behavioral problems). Some posts suggest that the OS or kernel may just be too out-of-date for the particular hardware, so since I've been wanting to switch to Neon anyway, I tried a fresh install of Neon 5.24 (different partition). Unfortunately, the behavior was the same: 100% functional OS, just *very* occasionally pages of the above message shown during bootup or shutdown.

1. Is there a chance that the actual physical SSD is faulty? It was purchased new.
2. If not, is the above of concern?
3. Is there a good solution? My understanding is that `pci=noaer` just tells it to disable advanced error reporting, which doesn't really seem like the best solution.

The system is a Dell Latitude 5490, and the BIOS is up to date. The SSD is a [Teamgroup MP34 4TB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08Z7LN8NM) (if that's relevant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was adding `pci=nommconf` to the kernel boot parameters, which disables Memory-Mapped PCI Configuration Space & reverts to the traditional handling of configuration space

Solution was found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/g8pbku/any_undesirable_side_effects_of_pcinommconf/).

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
pcie_aspm=off
```

Fixed the error (but for me, this is linked to GTX 660, not SSD).
But heard that it works for SSD, in fact taken from:
https://forums.unraid.net/topic/118286-nvme-drives-throwing-errors-filling-logs-instantly-how-to-resolve/?do=findComment&comment=1165150

From the above link:

> Could you try pcie_aspm=off  .  This seems to disable power management
> mode which is throwing the error.. I've put it in my config for next
> time I reboot.