Ubuntu 24.04 Incompatible with HP 15-au063nr?
HP Pavilion Notebook PC 15-au063nr,
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.59 GHz,
Installed RAM   12.0 GB (11.9 GB usable),
Display     1920x1080:
I had 23.10 running with "pci=noaer" added in GRUB and attempted an online upgrade (via "update-manager -d"). The process seemed to be progressing well until it asked if I wanted to keep a customized journal setting or revert to the default. I allowed it to revert, about a minute or two later the "Something went wrong" message appeared and the machine locked up. Attempted boots got as far as the password before a low drive space warning appeared and the machine cycled back to the login page.
I booted the 24.04 iso via USB and got as far as accessibility options before it too locked up. I finally got 23.04 with a legacy installer to run long enough to find both syslog.1 and kern.log.1 were over 20GB each. I did manage to delete them, but I cannot keep the laptop running on "Try Ubuntu" long enough to complete any installation (I assume the flash drive is getting overwhelmed by error messages). Attempted boots to the hard drive after deleting the massive log files still cycle from login to password to login...
I do recall setting a size limit to one log file (syslog?) at the time I discovered the pci=noaer argument. How can I 1) get 24.04 to run from the USB without hanging and 2) address the core error issue so Ubuntu does not need band-aids to function on this HP laptop?
Edit: the log-filling error report cycles repeatedly as
ubuntu kernel: [ time stamp] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
{next line}  device [8086:9d1b] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
{next line}   [ 0] RxErr   (First)
{next line} AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.0
These lines continue to repeat.
2nd Edit: I did get 24.04 running by editing GRUB (type "e" while the selection is highlighted) and adding "pci=noaer" after "quiet splash" both when booting from USB and after installation, so my first questioned is answered.

Firstly, the upgrade path has bugs, which is why Ubuntu does not automatically offer the upgrade yet https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/dont-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-yet

Your question is slightly unclear to me. It seems that you can boot try Ubuntu by editing the GRUB parameters. What is the issue then? Can you not install it?

To fix the error message, you may need to add another boot parameter after installing Ubuntu (if you can successfully install Ubuntu) https://askubuntu.com/a/1433404/124466

@Archisman Panigrahi I have multiple Ubuntu machines, thought I would try 24.04 on one... and did not find out about the online upgrade bugs (whatever they may be) until after the machine crashed. This issue is much larger than 24.04 and applies to 22.04, 23.04, and 23.10 as well (possibly other versions). As I mentioned in my 2nd edit above, I edited GRUB both for the USB and the normal boot after I guessed WHERE to add the pci=noaer argument. My machine is up; what about others trying to install Ubuntu on similar machines?
